# How to build properly "PUT method" and do "intern request"?

Tags: java, spring, rest, httprequest, put

I'm new to Spring and Java *(I might not use the right vocabulary, especially in English)*, and I'm trying to set up a tiny database. But I have issues with the syntax for the **PUT** method.
*(Everything is working for now)*

So I have a public class named **GameEntity**, it contains an **id**, a **name** and a list of objects named **PlayerEntity**
(I removed imports from the stackoverflow post just to see more clearly)

```
public class GameEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private List<PlayerEntity> players;

    public GameEntity() { }

    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public List<PlayerEntity> getPlayers() { return players; }
    public void setPlayers(List<PlayerEntity> players) { this.players = players; }
}
```

The **PlayerEntity** object is built the same way has **GameEntity** but simply have an **id** and a **name**.

Here is the mapping for **GET** and **POST** *(it is the same thing for **PlayerEntity**)*:

```
@RestController
public class GameController {
    private final GameRepository gameRepository;

    public GameController(GameRepository gameRepository) {
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/games")
    public List<GameEntity> getAllGames() {
        return this.gameRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/games")
    public GameEntity createGame(@RequestBody GameEntity gameEntity) {
        return this.gameRepository.save(gameEntity);
    }
}
```

Now, I can "**POST**" a **GameEntity** and a **PlayerEntity**, but I would like to had the **PlayerEntity** created to the list of **PlayerEntity** objects that is in the **GameEntity**.

So i guess that i will have to "**PUT**" the **GameEntity** created. But how can i "reach" the **PlayerEntity** ? Can i do something like internals requests ? What could be the syntax?
Doing two requests to create both objects and put one in the other is it the best way to do it ?
Am i missing something until now ?

I am a little bit lost, any advice would be a big help !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both objects can live independently they both should have a POST. I assume by the time Game is created your Player already exists? In such case when you POST Game you can include the players in its collection right away.

If you need to *update* the list of Players, there are multiple ways:

1. `PUT /game/{id}` that includes all the Players. Note that PUT should ideally overwrite the whole resource, so all the fields of Game should be included.
2. `PUT /game/{id}/players` replaces the list of previous Players with new Players. Again - whole list is included, but now you don't have to send all the fields of the Game.
3. `POST /game/{id}/player` - adds new players to the Game. This one is `POST` because such endpoint won't be idempotent anymore. If you go this way, you'll also have to create `DELETE /game/{id}/players`.
4. In case of even more complicated actions you may want to consider `PATCH` - it may be non-idempotent and can update the resource partially.

First 3 are RESTful, the last one isn't - it's possible that verbs may begin to crawl into the URI.

In general idempotent architecture is safer and simpler so you should start considering first 2. If it's complicated - #3 is also fine. If you think it doesn't work out (e.g. due to performance degradation or other factors) then you can consider the 4th option.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, i end up using the third method that you gave me :
Thank you a lot !